# Difference between "ga" vs "wo"

Tags: grammar, particle-が, particle-を

It's known that *roughly*, in most cases, we can think of using "wo" vs "ga" this way:

> ga is used when action is abstract, mental, non-physical
>
> otherwise, wo is used

Yet, these examples are in contradiction with that rule:

> Something ga taberarenai.
>
> Someone wo shitte iru.

Why is that? Are there any exceptions?

There are other examples as well I can remember for now.

Comment: The above first part presents itself as a quote... are you making it up or are you quoting something?

Answer (score 4):

As for your first example, potential forms of transitive verbs can take が instead of を. 食べられない (taberarenai) is the negative potential form of 食べる (taberu, "to eat"). が is used because no physical action has been taken yet when you say "can".

- [Potential Form](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/potential)

  > The potential form indicates that something is possible but no actual action is actually taken. While the potential form is still a verb, because it is describing the state of feasibility, in general, you don't want to use the direct object 「を」 as you would with the non-potential form of the verb.
- [The difference between が and を with the potential form of a verb.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/609/5010)
- [Why say "〜、皆には出来る。" instead of " 〜、皆は出来る。" in this context?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36481/5010)

  > One key to understanding how できる happens grammatically is that できる is often describing the thing that can be done, instead of the people or things doing the thing. Sometimes a closer gloss is *doable* rather than *can*

As for your second example, yes, 知る (shiru, "to learn; to get to know") is a transitive verb (a verb that takes を). 分かる (wakaru, "to understand") is a similar word but does not usually take を. I think this is something you have to remember and get used to.

- [How should I choose between [知]{し}る and わかる?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1659/5010)
- [知る vs わかる and when to use が and を in "how to" questions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14873/5010)

Comment: but is the rule I've mentioned correct?

Comment: @Ko32mo 好き (suki), 欲しい (hoshi) and such are actually *adjectives*. It's true that adjectives are sometimes used where English speakers normally use verbs. But I doubt it can be called a general rule.

Comment: but is the rule I've mentioned correct?

Comment: Incorrect. The rule you've mentioned is a severe oversimplification.

Comment: how about this https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12795/whats-the-difference-between-ga-and-o-when-they-are-used-to-designate-a-direc ?

Comment: **The general rule is that static verbs and adjectives take "ga" and "action verbs" take "o" on the direct object.**