# Justifying が into を

Tags: particle-が, particle-を

How do I handle a sentence in which I would normally have two が?
For example,

```
彼がその本を読んでる。
彼はその話題があまり分からん。
```

are normal sentences with slight distinction in meaning between が and は there, but what if I want a typical subject to use with 分かる?

```
彼がその話題が分からん
```

This doesn't work with two が, but I swear I hear this phrase often as

```
彼がその話題を分からん
```

Maybe I'm just mishearing, but is it possible to turn a second が into を for grammatical fit? Or are there other ways to express a が subject with a が verb?

Answer (score 4):

The following four sentences are all valid.

- 彼**は**その話題**が**分からない。
  He does not know about the topic.
- 彼**は**その話題**を**分からない。
  He does not know about the topic.
- 彼**が**その話題**が**分からない。
  It is he who does not know about the topic.
- 彼**が**その話題**を**分からない。
  It is he who does not know about the topic.

As for the difference between 彼**は** and 彼**が**, the former is the normal particle choice, as you probably know. If you use が here, it will carry an exhaustive-listing meaning. See: [What's the difference between wa (は) and ga (が)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/22/5010)

As for the difference between その話題**が**分からない and その話題**を**分からない, they mean the same thing, but the former is still considered more standard. Some expressions including 好き, 分かる, ～(ら)れる and ～たい sometimes take を, but it's difficult to make a clear distinction, and the level of acceptance varies from person to person. See the following questions for details.

- [Usage of ～を好き outside of embedded clauses](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26005/5010) (See Darius Jahandarie's answer)
- [The difference between が and を with the potential form of a verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/609/5010)
- [Difference between "ga" vs "wo"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/52123/5010)
- [Difference between particles wa, ga and o with sukidesu](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/44409/5010)

When exhaustive-listing が is involved, you can safely use two が's in one sentence, and just because there are two が's doesn't mean you have to replace the second が with を.

Comment: Can I get a little more background? Because the third sentence,
彼がその話題が分からない, has been described by all native speakers as unnatural. Are you a native speaker? Or is there a lesser-used grammatical rule?

Comment: @user33717 Yes I am a native speaker of Japanese. 彼がその話題が分からない makes sense, but only in certain contexts. It would indeed sound awful if said out of nowhere, but I didn't go into detail because I thought you already knew why... Do you understand how exhaustive-listing ga works in general?