# 「〜そうにない」 unfamiliar usage of そう

Tags: grammar, translation

I'm playing a video game in Japanese, and one of the characters said

> 僕にもわかり**そうにない**。

I understand that (verb stem)そう means "it seems" or "it appears", but I've never seen (verb stem)そう used with the に particle.

My guess is that the sentence means something like:

> I don't seem to know either.

Am I translating it correctly? What is the meaning of this construction?

Comment: As for your second sentence, are you sure you've never seen V + **しか** ない (e.g. 諦めるしかない)?

Comment: @Earthliŋ No, I've only seen しかない used with nouns (e.g. コンピュータが一台しかない), but I now realize that my confusion with this sentence isn't related to そう, so I'll edit it out of the question.

Comment: As you can see [here](http://www.weblio.jp/content/そうにない) そうにない is a phrase and it means "doesn't seems like; extremely unlikely to". So I think that your translation is correct.

Comment: You may be interested in the [difference between 知る and 分かる](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/). 「分かりそうにない」 is "unlikely that I can understand (the difficult textbook, concept, etc.)" as opposed to just knowing something as a fact.

Comment: @naruto Yes, I know the difference between the two.

Comment: @Ataraxia If you don't mind me asking, what video game was it?

Comment: @Toyu_Frey Man it's been a while, but I _think_ it was Tales of Xillia 2

Answer (score 1):

Your translation is correct.
「そう」is for positive sentence, 「そうに」is for negative sentence.
「そう」/「そうに」also have some meaning of "in the future".

I also understand.

> 僕にもわかります
>   僕にもわかる

I understand... maybe.

> 僕にもわかりそうです
>   僕にもわかりそう

I don't understand.

> 僕にはわかりません
>   僕にはわからない

I don't understand, ether.

> 僕にもわかりません
>   僕にもわからない

It's hard to understand. Ask someone else.
「そうもない」is much harder to achieve the goal than 「そうにない」.

> 僕にはわかりそうもありません
>   僕にはわかりそうもない

I don't understand ether.
Nearly same as 「わからない」 but 「わかりそうにない」is a little bit soft.

> 僕にもわかりそうにない

"(I'll try but..) it seems too dificult for me to understand"
「わからなそうです」is more softer expression

> 僕にもわからなそうです