# What does 癖になっても mean here?

Tags: translation

Looking for japanese songs and found this one. https://mojim.com/jpy136351x1x6.htm

This is the line I'm having trouble understanding.

> 癖になっても知らないよ

Dictionary says 癖 can mean vice or bad habit, and I've learned what なる means. I'm just not sure how 知らないよ fits into this. Like "I don't know how this becomes a bad habit."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[癖になる](https://jisho.org/search/%E7%99%96%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B) is a set phrase that primarily means "to develop a (bad) habit", but it also means "to develop a love/taste (for something)". For example 癖になる味 refers to an acquired taste, i.e., a taste you gradually start to appreciate, like that of blue cheese or *natto*.

This 知らないよ means "I don't care" or "don't blame me" rather than "I don't know". This is one of the common meanings of 知らない. See: [知らない used in "I don't care"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41143/5010)

> 癖になっても知らないよ
>   I don't care if you get addicted (to this starry night at Shibuya)!